# Why is MediaWiki giving me an internal error?

Tags: linux, database, mediawiki

When I try to access my MediaWiki install, I get this:

```
[126acc5486e3f05c51e0c77b] /taerelwiki/index.php/Taerel_Worldbuilding_Wiki Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError: A database query error has occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema updater after upgrading or after adding a new extension?

Please see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Upgrading and https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:How_to_debug for more information.

Error 1932: Table 'taerelwiki.l10n_cache' doesn't exist in engine
Function: LCStoreDB::get
Query: SELECT lc_value FROM `l10n_cache` WHERE lc_lang = 'en-gb' AND lc_key = 'deps' LIMIT 1
Backtrace:

from /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1618)
#0 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1602): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->getQueryException()
#1 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1576): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->getQueryExceptionAndLog()
#2 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(952): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError()
#3 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1708): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query()
#4 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1661): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->select()
#5 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(103): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->selectField()
#6 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(312): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->__call()
#7 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LCStoreDB.php(61): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->selectField()
#8 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LocalisationCache.php(451): LCStoreDB->get()
#9 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LocalisationCache.php(497): LocalisationCache->isExpired()
#10 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LocalisationCache.php(373): LocalisationCache->initLanguage()
#11 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LocalisationCache.php(314): LocalisationCache->loadItem()
#12 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LanguageFallback.php(106): LocalisationCache->getItem()
#13 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LanguageFactory.php(186): MediaWiki\Languages\LanguageFallback->getAll()
#14 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LanguageFactory.php(144): MediaWiki\Languages\LanguageFactory->newFromCode()
#15 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/MapCacheLRU.php(274): MediaWiki\Languages\LanguageFactory->MediaWiki\Languages\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LanguageFactory.php(141): MapCacheLRU->getWithSetCallback()
#17 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/language/LanguageFactory.php(128): MediaWiki\Languages\LanguageFactory->getRawLanguage()
#18 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/ServiceWiring.php(452): MediaWiki\Languages\LanguageFactory->getLanguage()
#19 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(445): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer::{closure}()
#20 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(411): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->createService()
#21 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(301): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->getService()
#22 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(855): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getService()
#23 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/ServiceWiring.php(2060): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getContentLanguage()
#24 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(445): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer::{closure}()
#25 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/vendor/wikimedia/services/src/ServiceContainer.php(411): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->createService()
#26 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(301): Wikimedia\Services\ServiceContainer->getService()
#27 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/MediaWikiServices.php(1940): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getService()
#28 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/session/SessionManager.php(224): MediaWiki\MediaWikiServices->getUserNameUtils()
#29 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/session/SessionManager.php(130): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->__construct()
#30 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/Setup.php(440): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::singleton()
#31 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/WebStart.php(86): require_once(string)
#32 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/index.php(44): require(string)
#33 {main}
```

I tried to run update.php and get this

```
MediaWiki 1.39.0 Updater

Your composer.lock file is up to date with current dependencies!
Going to run database updates for taerelwiki
Depending on the size of your database this may take a while!
Abort with control-c in the next five seconds (skip this countdown with --quick) ...0
Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError from line 1618 of /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: Error 1932: Table 'taerelwiki.categorylinks' doesn't exist in engine
Function: DatabaseUpdater::doCollationUpdate
Query: SELECT  COUNT(*)  FROM `categorylinks`    WHERE cl_collation != 'uppercase'  LIMIT 1  

#0 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1602): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->getQueryException()
#1 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1576): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->getQueryExceptionAndLog()
#2 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(952): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError()
#3 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1708): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query()
#4 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1661): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->select()
#5 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(103): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->selectField()
#6 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DBConnRef.php(312): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->__call()
#7 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(1152): Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBConnRef->selectField()
#8 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/includes/installer/DatabaseUpdater.php(510): DatabaseUpdater->doCollationUpdate()
#9 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/maintenance/update.php(202): DatabaseUpdater->doUpdates()
#10 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/maintenance/includes/MaintenanceRunner.php(309): UpdateMediaWiki->execute()
#11 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/maintenance/doMaintenance.php(85): MediaWiki\Maintenance\MaintenanceRunner->run()
#12 /var/www/html/taerelwiki/maintenance/update.php(312): require_once('...')
#13 {main}
root@jammy-bare:/var/www/html/taerelwiki/maintenance#
```

The tables as per `SHOW FULL TABLES;`:

```
MariaDB [taerelwiki]> +------------------------+------------+
    -> | Tables_in_taerelwiki   | Table_type |
    -> +------------------------+------------+
    -> | actor                  | BASE TABLE |
    -> | archive                | BASE TABLE |
    -> | bot_passwords          | BASE TABLE |
    -> | category               | BASE TABLE |
    -> | categorylinks          | BASE TABLE |
    -> | change_tag             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | change_tag_def         | BASE TABLE |
    -> | comment                | BASE TABLE |
    -> | content                | BASE TABLE |
    -> | content_models         | BASE TABLE |
    -> | externallinks          | BASE TABLE |
    -> | filearchive            | BASE TABLE |
    -> | image                  | BASE TABLE |
    -> | imagelinks             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | interwiki              | BASE TABLE |
    -> | ip_changes             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | ipblocks               | BASE TABLE |
    -> | ipblocks_restrictions  | BASE TABLE |
    -> | iwlinks                | BASE TABLE |
    -> | job                    | BASE TABLE |
    -> | l10n_cache             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | langlinks              | BASE TABLE |
    -> | linktarget             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | log_search             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | logging                | BASE TABLE |
    -> | module_deps            | BASE TABLE |
    -> | objectcache            | BASE TABLE |
    -> | oldimage               | BASE TABLE |
    -> | page                   | BASE TABLE |
    -> | page_props             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | page_restrictions      | BASE TABLE |
    -> | pagelinks              | BASE TABLE |
    -> | protected_titles       | BASE TABLE |
    -> | querycache             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | querycache_info        | BASE TABLE |
    -> | querycachetwo          | BASE TABLE |
    -> | recentchanges          | BASE TABLE |
    -> | redirect               | BASE TABLE |
    -> | revision               | BASE TABLE |
    -> | revision_comment_temp  | BASE TABLE |
    -> | searchindex            | BASE TABLE |
    -> | site_identifiers       | BASE TABLE |
    -> | site_stats             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | sites                  | BASE TABLE |
    -> | slot_roles             | BASE TABLE |
    -> | slots                  | BASE TABLE |
    -> | templatelinks          | BASE TABLE |
    -> | text                   | BASE TABLE |
    -> | updatelog              | BASE TABLE |
    -> | uploadstash            | BASE TABLE |
    -> | user                   | BASE TABLE |
    -> | user_autocreate_serial | BASE TABLE |
    -> | user_former_groups     | BASE TABLE |
    -> | user_groups            | BASE TABLE |
    -> | user_newtalk           | BASE TABLE |
    -> | user_properties        | BASE TABLE |
    -> | watchlist              | BASE TABLE |
    -> | watchlist_expiry       | BASE TABLE |
    -> +------------------------+------------+
    -> 58 rows in set (0.002 sec)
    ->
```

The problem is that MediaWiki is not working with those errors. I think there may be  a missing database table, but unsure how to resore it as `updata.php` is showing the error from the 2nd code block.

Comment: Did you forget to run the upgrader?

Comment: I did try using php.update php, the version of Mediawiki both old and new is 1.39. Codeblock #2 is what happens

Comment: Create the required table, categorylinks, manually yourself. Best solution would be create a second instance and dump the table then import the table.

Comment: I just dropped and remade the tables and reinstalled Mediawiki. Imports are slow, but seem to be working.  A messy way to fix, but probly was the  more simple for me

Comment: That seems like it was overkill since you were only missing a single table